# When proving that f(z) is a polynomial, is it enough to consider just one point instead of keeping z arbitrary?

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, laurent-series, taylor-expansion

I think so - but I'd rather ask the MSE community too.

Say I am given the bound |f(z)| < $|z|^3$, and that f is entire.  Show f must be a polynomial.

I used Cauchy's Integral Formula for derivatives and showed that for n>3, all of the derivatives are zero, when we let the closed contour grow to infinity.

But, I have only used CIF at the point z = 0 - I didn't keep z arbitrary.

Then the CIF shows that, at z = 0, the Taylor series has only finitely many terms and so f(z) must be a polynomial.

So I feel there's actually no need to apply the CIF to an arbitrary z.

We have enough information on f(z) just from looking at z=0.

Thanks,

Comment: Oh, very nice way of using the identity theorem @DaenerysNaharis.  But... I think it would be "since the plane is connected"?  It's the connectedness of the set that makes the two functions agree everywhere, once they agree on a smaller subset of the connected set.

Comment: Ok, gotcha @DaenerysNaharis.  The way I've seen it is:  proofs of this type usually keep z arbitrary - but I don't feel it's necessary.  E.g., if our unknown function f(z), given some upper bound to assume, turns out to be a polynomial near the origin ... can it be *anything* else on the complex plane?  That's really my question, I guess...

Comment: If two holomorphic functions on the same domain are equal on any open set in that domain, they are identically equal.

Comment: Here's a hint, in lieu of an actual answer: You should be able to prove (or look up the proof in your textbook) that the CIF for entire functions doesn't actually depend on choice of integrating contour, beyond that it be a simple closed curve. From this, can you prove that the choice of basepoint doesn't matter?

Comment: ...hmm...is it because we can push the basepoint, $z_0$ to the origin anyway?

Comment: I don't seem to get a nice bound, though, when I re-do this problem, again using the estimates given by the CIF.  The integrand would now be something such as f(z)/ (z-$z_0$)^(n+1)

Comment: and using the bound given in the question gives an upper bound of |z|^3 / R^(n+1), which is sort of awkward -- can't do much with the factor |z|^3.

Comment: Yes, it is enough to consider only one point when you take _all_ derivatives of order $> m$ at that point into account. If you consider all points in some non-empty open set (typically a disk $D_\varepsilon(0)$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$), then it suffices to consider one derivative (here the fourth) and show it vanishes on that open set. Which method you prefer is a matter of taste.

Comment: Hi @DanielFischer, regarding your first suggestion, my concern is, showing that all derivatives of order > m at zero...are zero shows that f(z) locally behaves like a polynomial.  But...can it possibly be something else...weird... away from the origin?  I guess I'm trying to say something about uniqueness here and can't quite do it 100%.  But I *can* say that f entire has a power series with an infinite radius of convergence, so expanding at zero, f agrees with its Taylor representation on the whole complex plane, so f must be a polynomial.  Would this be enough, you think?  Thanks,

Comment: ...so that perhaps, specific to entire functions, if you know its behavior locally, then you know it globally on C (no singularities to classify and study.)

Comment: The crucial property is not being entire, but being analytic. If $U$ is a connected open set, and $f\colon U\to \mathbb{C}$ is analytic - that is, for every $z_0\in U$, there is an $r(z_0) > 0$ so that on the disk $D_{r(z_0)}(z_0)$ there is a power series representing $f$ [$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (z-z_0)^n$ on the disk] - then $f$ is completely determined by its Taylor series at one point of $U$. It's the identity theorem for analytic functions. Then note that a function is holomorphic if and only if it is analytic.

Comment: Ok, got it.  Thanks so much, @danielfischer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition $|f(z)| < |z|^3$ should be $|f(z)| \le |z|^3$, otherwise we get $0\le |f(0)| < |0^3| = 0$.

The condition implies that $0$ is a zero of $f$ of order at least $3$ (see below) and so $f(z)=z^3 g(z)$ with $g$ entire and bounded.  Hence $g$ is constant by Liouville's theorem.

Indeed, $|f(z)| \le |z|^3$ implies $|f(0)|\le0$ and so $f(0)=0$. Write $f(z)=z f_1(z)$ with $f_1$ entire. Then $|f_1(z)| \le |z|^2$ and as before this implies $f_1(0)=0$. Repeat the argument twice and conclude that $f(z)=z^3 g(z)$ with $g$ entire and $|g(z)|\le1$.

Comment: Hi @lhf, how do you get a zero at 0 of at least order 3?  The order of the zero at 0 for f is the smallest k such that f^(k), the k^th derivative of f, evaluated at zero, is non-zero.  Are you referring to this definition?  Because with this definition, we should *start* with 0 derivatives...before we land at a non-zero derivative and can then read off the order of the zero.  Also -- how is g bounded? The upper bound of |z|^3 for f(z) doesn't make f bounded; it just makes f grow like a polynomial, which, for non-constant polynomials, *must* grow to infinity...thanks,

Comment: -- I am intrigued, though, and really hope that your answer is correct.  I would *love* an alternate proof (such as yours) to this classic question...

Comment: well...using the upper bound given, then |z|^3 * |g(z)| < |z|^3, which shows that g(z) is indeed bounded and entire, hence constant.  So, my only question is how you got the order of the zero at 0 for f(z) to be at least 3...

Comment: my estimate from the CIF, and using the bound given in the question, gives me n!R^(3-n).  so, for n>3 and R going to infinity, that estimate goes to zero.  so the 4th, 5th, ... derivatives are all zero.  But, n!R^(3-n) for n less than or equal to 3 is of course *not* zero at 0.

Comment: ...or, you are using the argument principle and Rouche's theorem...

Comment: Hi @lhf, using this, if i let f(z) = h(z) - z^3, then with the bound, I get that |h(z) - z^3| < |z|^3 and by Rouche's theorem, h(z) has 3 zeroes, since g(z) = z^3 has 3 zeroes (at z=0).  But Rouche's theorem doesn't tell us the *location* of the zeroes of h(z)...so we have h(z) = (z-$z_0$)(z-$z_1$)(z-$z_2$)g(z)

Comment: @LebronJames, see my edited answer.

Comment: This is such a cool proof.  Thanks so much, @lhf.